# Задача с курса Stepik "Задачи по программированию на языке C++"

Tags: c++

Не получается решить задачу с курса. Проваливает 3-й тест.

`Failed test #3 of 11. Wrong answer`

Условие задачи:

*Вводятся два двузначных натуральных числа. Догадайтесь по двум открытым тестам, какую надо написать программу, чтобы она прошла все оставшиеся закрытые наборы исходных данных.*

`Sample Input 1:` 12 34

`Sample Output 1:` 64

`Sample Input 2:` 98 76

`Sample Output 2:` 156

Вот мое решение, которое проходит первые два теста.
Берем сумму цифр и используем деление для увеличение разряда:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b;
    cin >> a >> b;
    int n11 = a / 10 % 10;
    int n12 = a % 10;
    int n21 = b / 10 % 10;
    int n22 = b % 10;
    int first = n12 + n22;
    int second = n11 + n21;
    cout << first + second / 10 << second % 10;
    return 0;
}
```

Заранее благодарю за помощь!

Comment: Ну значит неправильно догадался, чо...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Идея очень проста:

```
Пример 1.
Число 12 преобразуем в 21, а число 34 в 43. Имеем: 43+21=65

Пример 2.
Число 98 => 89, 76 = > 67. В сумме: 156
```

Вам просто необходимо поменять цифры местами в числе.